# Stop 'Div' from changing position 'hover'

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to build an audio player using HTML, CSS and Jquery. I'm having trouble with the 'hover' method using Jquery. It seems to move the div down when the 'background-image' is removed - why is this? I understand that has to do with the flow of the page. Thinking I should start the audio player again from scratch as there is too much wrong with it. Should I just use CSS hover?

Here is a link to the live [site](https://benjamingibbsportfolio.000webhostapp.com/index.html#)

```js
$('.music-box').hover(function() {
  $('.music-box').css("border", "1px solid black");
  $('.music-box').css("background", "none");
  $('.player').css('display', 'block');
  $('.music-details').css('display', 'block');
  $('.buyDiv').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.music-box').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.music-box').css("border", "none");
  $('.music-box').css("background", "url('junction.jpg')");
  $('.music-box').css("background-size", "contain");
  $('.music-box').css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
  $('.player').css('display', 'none');
  $('.music-details').css('display', 'none');
  $('.buyDiv').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.junction {
  display: inline;
  padding: 2vw; 
}
.music-box {
  background: url(junction.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 16vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
.music-details {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 5vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1vh;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.appleLink {
  height: 3vh;
  width: auto;
}
.player {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 7vh;
}
.buyDiv {
  display: none;
  height: 3vh;
  top: 9vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.buyList {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.buyList li {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.buyFnt {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1vh;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="junction">
  <div class="music-box">
    <h3 class="music-details">Junction - EP
      <br>
      <br>
      Turn Around (feat Madi Lane)
      <br>
      <br>
      My Nu Leng - 2018
    </h3>
    <audio id="player" src="tune.mp3"></audio>

    <div class="player"> 
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><img class="playBtn" src="playBtn.png"></button> 
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"><img class="stopBtn" src="stopBtn.png"></button> 
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1"><img class="volUp" src="volUp.png"></button> </button> 
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1"><img class="volDown" src="volDown.png"></button> </button> 
    </div>
      <div class="buyDiv">
        <ul class="buyList">
          <li class="buyFnt">BUY</li>
          <li><button><img class="appleLink" src="apple.png"></button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: So what exactly do we need to hover on that live site example, to see the effect your are talking about? Because I can’t spot it anywhere. And what makes you think this had to do with the background image in particular? Especially considering that you are manipulating other stuff as well, such as borders – which are much more likely to influence element layout/dimensions to begin with.

Comment: _“Should I just use CSS hover?”_ - if there is no need to do anything in JS in the first place - then yes, that is almost always the preferable alternative.

Comment: Sorry on the 'releases' section when you hover over artwork, the 'div' jumps and clips rather than staying in position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are small changes to be done to make it perfect.
Add float attribute and background-position to music box class(.music-box) css as follows:

```
.music-box{
     float:left;
     background-position: center !important;
}
```

**This worked on your website and I have tested on your site.**

Comment: Yeah, this is good but changes the layout. Gives me something to work on thanks.

Comment: @designtocode It can be fixed with few lines of css as required. I can help you if needed

Comment: Yes, please. I've been trying to figure it out for ages.

Comment: Think i fixed it, added float left to the list item and added padding to the container to center the list

Comment: Can you green check this answer Benjamin?

Answer (score 1):

There could be interference from other CSS/JS. I copied your code into a Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lkm4fotd/1/

HTML

```
<ul class="first-row">


                        <li class="junction">
                            <div class="music-box">
                                <h3 class="music-details">Junction - EP
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    Turn Around (feat Madi Lane)
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    My Nu Leng - 2018
                                </h3>
                                <audio id="player" src="tune.mp3"></audio>

                                <div class="player"> 
                                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><img class="playBtn" src="playBtn.png"></button> 
                                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"><img class="stopBtn" src="stopBtn.png"></button> 
                                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1"><img class="volUp" src="volUp.png"></button>  
                                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1"><img class="volDown" src="volDown.png"></button>  
                                </div>
                                    <div class="buyDiv">
                                        <ul class="buyList">
                                            <li class="buyFnt">BUY</li>
                                            <li><button><img class="appleLink" src="apple.png"></button></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

CSS: Your css file

JS:

```
$('.music-box').hover(function() {
    $('.music-box').css("border", "1px solid black");
    $('.music-box').css("background", "none");
    $('.player').css('display', 'block');
    $('.music-details').css('display', 'block');
    $('.buyDiv').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.music-box').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.music-box').css("border", "none");
    $('.music-box').css("background", "url('https://benjamingibbsportfolio.000webhostapp.com/junction.jpg')");
    $('.music-box').css("background-size", "contain");
    $('.music-box').css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
    $('.player').css('display', 'none');
    $('.music-details').css('display', 'none');
    $('.buyDiv').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think it may be due to the image size or some positioning error, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I can suggest stripping out elements/js/css one by one and see if it fixes it. You could also try change the container :) Good luck!